# Make Components in CardLayout Purposely Invisible When Switched

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Problem: Using CardLayout, when I run the app and switch the to the other card all components show. I want components that are associated with JPanel card3 to not show when I switch the other card. Is this possible?

I want to have card3 components (essentially just four buttons) not show when cardlayout is switched.

```
public class App2 implements ActionListener {
JPanel cards; 
final static String BUTTONPANEL = "Switch Mode";
final static String TEXTPANEL = "Card with JTextField";

public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
    JPanel comboBoxPane = new JPanel();
    String comboBoxItems[] = { BUTTONPANEL, TEXTPANEL };
    JButton jb = new JButton("Switch Mode");
    jb.setFocusable(false);
    jb.addActionListener(this);
    comboBoxPane.add(jb);

    //Create the "cards".
    JPanel card1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,1));
    comboBoxPane.add(card1);

    JPanel card3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,1));
    comboBoxPane.add(card3);

    card1.add(new JLabel("Current Mode: Edit"));
    card1.add(new JLabel("Question"));
    card1.add(new JTextField(30));
    card1.add(new JLabel("Answer"));
    card1.add(new JTextField(30));

    card3.add(new JButton("Previous"));
    card3.add(new JButton("Next"));
    card3.add(new JButton("Add"));
    card3.add(new JButton("Save"));

    JPanel card2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,1));
    card2.add(new JLabel("Current Mode: Test"));
    card2.add(new JLabel("Question"));
    card2.add(new JTextField("", 20));
    card2.add(new JLabel("Answer"));
    card2.add(new JTextField("", 20));


    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    cards.add(card1, BUTTONPANEL);
    cards.add(card2, TEXTPANEL);

    pane.add(comboBoxPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
    cl.show(cards, TEXTPANEL);  
    card3.setVisible(false);
}


private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Flash Cards");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    App2 demo = new App2();
    demo.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Set the initial state of the components on card 3 to be invisible.  If you seperate your UI into individual classes, then you will get more control and flexibility which will make doing these things simpler

Comment: Could you provide the syntax or an example of that?

Comment: Well, since you're doing things like `card2.add(new JLabel("Question"));`, you'll find it hard, you need a reference to the component(s) and simply use `setVisible(false)` to hide them

Comment: I only want them to not be visible in the second card layout. setVisible(false) would set them false in both layouts no?

Comment: Since a component can only reside on a single parent, both panels will need their own instances of the components, this is why I recommend creating a custom class(es), which extends from `JPanel` and place the logic for the each panel into them, this will make your life much simpler in the long run